# Usage of "affiliate"

Tags: grammar

I was told that in American English you cannot use "affiliate" the way it's done in the following example, but in European English it would be permissible. Is this true?

> ... we should, to varying degrees, either affiliate them or develop relations with them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure either way you have to affiliate *with* something... so change the sentence to one of the following: 1) "... either affiliate *with* them or develop relations with them" 2) "... either affiliate or develop relations with them"

Comment: [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/affiliate) requires a prepositional phrase: verb 1. (tr; foll by to or with) to receive into close connection or association (with a larger body, group, organization, etc); adopt as a member, branch, etc
2. (foll by with) to associate (oneself) or be associated, esp as a subordinate or subsidiary; bring or come into close connection ⇒ _he affiliated himself with the Union_.

Answer (score 1):

As a verb, "affiliate" has a few subtly different meanings.

One is similar in meaning to "make friends" or "become friends".

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/affiliate)

> to attach or unite on terms of fellowship; associate (usually followed by with in U.S. usage, by to in Brit. usage):
>   *"to affiliate with the church."*

We would not say *"We should become friends them."* - we would instead say *"We should become friends **with** them"*.  It's the same with *affiliate* here - we should say *"... we should, to varying degrees, either affiliate **with** them or develop relations with them."*

So, if that's the intended meaning of "affiliate" here, then it's wrong.

On the other hand, another definition is similar in meaning to "adopt" or "bring within your own organisation":

[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/affiliated)

> 1. To adopt or accept as a member, subordinate associate, or branch: *"The HMO affiliated the clinics last year."*

and this doesn't require *"with"*.

So, it could be correct, depending on what's being said.  If the author is talking about "making friends" with them then it's wrong.  If the author is talking about actually bringing them into his own organisation, as a member, then it's right.

Looking at the small amount of context presented here, I don't think it's possible to say for sure what was intended.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth can you explain the purpose of "AHDEL" in the edit please?

Comment: Answers need to be correctly attributed; the definition that follows is ultimately from the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language.... This answer would seem to indicate OP has got it the wrong way round.